# Bash: creating file names according to directory names

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory, filenames

Say I have a directory structure that is like `Parent_dir/<name>/<date>/`

How can I use a bash script placed into `Parent_dir` to navigate through every `/<name>/<date>/` subdirectory and create a blank text file named `<name>_<date>.txt` within `/<name>/<date>/` subdirectory?

Comment: Are `name` and `date ` placeholders as well?

Comment: yes there's 20 different "name" directories (some have spaces if that matters) and 93 different "date" directories within each

Comment: edited my post to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Where the new files would be created?

Comment: sorry made another edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the filenames to literally be named `name_date.txt`, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d)
do
    touch "$dir"/name_date.txt
done
```

If you want the filenames to be `<name>_<date>.txt`, do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type d)
do
    for subdir in $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type d)
    do
        base_dir=$(basename $dir)
        base_subdir=$(basename $subdir)

        touch "$base_dir"/"$base_subdir"/"$base_dir"_"$base_subdir".txt
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks this works great except for it doesn't work for <name> directories that have spaces in them. Is there any quick fix for that?

Comment: Try now - the IFS should fix it. It's a bit of a hack, but should work.

Comment: Perfect much appreciated!

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) Learn how to do it the right way and there won't be any need for "hacks"...

Answer (score 4):

From the `Parent_dir`:

```
for d in */*/; do f=${d/\//_}; touch -- "$d"/"${f::-1}.txt"; done
```

Note that `touch` will change the timestamp of any existing file.

You can do a dry-run first with replacing `touch` with `echo`:

```
for d in */*/; do f=${d/\//_}; echo -- "$d"/"${f::-1}.txt"; done
```

- `for d in */*/` lets us iterating over the directories two levels deep
- `f=${d/\//_}` replaces first directory separator `/` with `_` and save the output as variable `f`
- `"$d"/"${f::-1}.txt"` expands to the directory name, followed by the desired filename; `${f::-1}` strips off the last `/` from variable `f`

Note that, as the directory separator `/` is present with variable `d`, the `/` in `"$d"/"${f::-1}.txt"` is redundant; as almost all systems take `//` as single `/`, this should not be a problem. Alternately, you can drip `/`:

```
for d in */*/; do f=${d/\//_}; touch -- "${d}${f::-1}.txt"; done
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out later because it looks very clean although the first post seemed to work for my needs :)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   case ${1//[!\/]/} in
      "//" ) f=${1:2}; f=${f/\//_}; :> "$1/$f.txt" ;;
      * ) false ;;
   esac
' {} {} \; -prune

for d in */*/; do
   f=${d/\//_}
   :> "${d%?}/${f%?}.txt"
done
```

Comment: Rakesh buddy, please add some explanation to your posts as they keep showing up in the _Low Quality Post_ review queue due to the fact there's only code and no text (I just had to review three of them)...